# How to get Android studio to see Android things raspberry PI as deployment target

Tags: android-studio, raspberry-pi, android-things

How do I get android studio to see raspberry PI as deployment target.

I have flashed my raspberry PI with android things. Its working because I can see it on screen attached to raspberry PI. My wifi and Ethernet are connected to raspberry PI. I have built a program to have button light led in android studio. When I click on run it cant find raspberry PI as a deployment target. I'm using same cable that I use to connect to my galaxy note.
Any ideas?

Comment: Check this link: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html

Comment: I have flashed android things onto raspberry pi and its working. How do I now load my program onto raspberry pi

Comment: Check the **Step 2: Connect the Hardware** section...it says how to connect your device using adb.

Comment: Are you saying I have to use the adb tool to load program? It cant be done from android studio

Comment: Yes....you have to connect via **adb**.

Comment: “Getting started with Android Things with Raspberry Pi(part 1)” @ajinkyabadve https://medium.com/@ajinkyabadve/getting-started-with-android-things-with-raspberry-pi-part-1-1059cb870e93 this might help you...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the micro USB port to connect your raspberry pi to adb and Android studio. It does not support that data connection. You will need to connect over WiFi or Ethernet with `adb connect [ip address]`